# Parse Error, Inserting PHP code in MyBB

Tags: php, parse-error, mybb

I'm inserting this code in the `<head> </head>` for a mybb forum:

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['url'])): // <-- only include jQuery if url set ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
      height: 140,
      modal: true
    });
  });
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Seeing two errors at the top of the page saying

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/content/87/9583687/html/a/global.php(524) : eval()'d code(2) : eval()'d code on line 1

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF in /home/content/87/9583687/html/a/global.php(524) : eval()'d code(14) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

Is there any issue or syntax problem with first line code? I mean this:

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['url'])): // <-- only include jQuery if url set ?>
```

Thank you!

**UPDATE::**

Thank you! I have tried but I think i'm sure some mistakes? :/

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['url'])): 
$str = <<<EOD
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
      height: 140,
      modal: true
    });
  });
</script>
EOD;
echo $str;
endif;
?>
```

**"UPDATE"**

This is the actual file named **headerinclude** :

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="{$lang->latest_threads} (RSS 2.0)" href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/syndication.php" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="{$lang->latest_threads} (Atom 1.0)" href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/syndication.php?type=atom1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset={$charset}" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/jscripts/prototype.js?ver=1603"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/jscripts/general.js?ver=1603"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/jscripts/popup_menu.js?ver=1600"></script>
{$stylesheets}
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    var cookieDomain = "{$mybb->settings['cookiedomain']}";
    var cookiePath = "{$mybb->settings['cookiepath']}";
    var cookiePrefix = "{$mybb->settings['cookieprefix']}";
    var deleteevent_confirm = "{$lang->deleteevent_confirm}";
    var removeattach_confirm = "{$lang->removeattach_confirm}";
    var loading_text = '{$lang->ajax_loading}';
    var saving_changes = '{$lang->saving_changes}';
    var use_xmlhttprequest = "{$mybb->settings['use_xmlhttprequest']}";
    var my_post_key = "{$mybb->post_code}";
    var imagepath = "{$theme['imgdir']}";
// -->
</script>
{$newpmmsg}
```

I want to add below php code in this file:

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['url'])): // <-- only include jQuery if url set ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
      height: 140,
      modal: true
    });
  });
  </script>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

This headerinclude file included in the file Global.php in this way:

```
// Set up some of the default templates
eval("\$headerinclude = \"".$templates->get("headerinclude")."\";");
eval("\$gobutton = \"".$templates->get("gobutton")."\";");
eval("\$htmldoctype = \"".$templates->get("htmldoctype", 1, 0)."\";");
eval("\$header = \"".$templates->get("header")."\";");
```

Comment: Is it your full file? or there are more contents around it. Please post everything that produces this error.

Comment: Hi, I've added another update. Please have a look.

Comment: i've already included the error in the start of the question.

Comment: aren't you making the same mistake?

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need this plugin : [PHP in Templates / Complex Templates](http://mybbhacks.zingaburga.com/showthread.php?tid=260/)

Because MyBB don't allow to use `<?php ... ?>` inside the template. But if you use that plugin, you can but it has some limitations (you can see in the link I provide)

This plugin is the most powerful plugin I ever seen for MyBB. For example, if I don't want the guest to see New Thread in forumdisplay.php, I just need to change the template to:

```
<if $mybb->user['uid'] != 0 then>
    <a href="newthread.php?fid={$fid}>New Thread</a>
</if>
```

Have fun with MyBB!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, phpBB will put everything inside `<?php ?>` blocks in an `eval`. In your case this means it throws

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['url'])):
```

in an `eval`. And that is an unfinished `if` construct. To fix it, put the entire PHP code inside **one** `<?php ?>` block. Use strings handling or [HERE documents](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to do the HTML.

Example HEREDOC:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_REQUEST['url'])):
       $str = <<<EOD
... put your HTML here ...
EOD;
       echo $str;
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I have updated the code above, can you check it please?

Comment: Please update you question so the formatting isn't lost. Just put it at the end after "UPDATE".